# Turkish characters not working for Google Raleway font

Tags: unicode, fonts, google-font-api, turkish, unicode-range

I am using a special WordPress theme along with the Google **Raleway** (ExtraLight) font. Some Turkish characters on my site are not working well, although Raleway font has support for Turkish.

The system does not use template font directory.

I see the following line in the source:
[`http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A200%7CMontserrat%3A700&subset=latin&ver=1442092301`](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A200%7CMontserrat%3A700&subset=latin&ver=1442092301)

What must I do to for the Turkish characters to work properly? I see `unicode-range` line on the googleapis.com's CSS - is it related to this problem?  Please advise. I need to be able to use the following Turkish characters: `ş`, `Ş`, `İ`, `ı`, `ğ`, `Ğ`.

Answer (score 1):

You request the font with the query parameter `subset=latin`. So you get only the latin glyphs. I bet Turkish glyphs are in some other subset.

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Subsets

Update:

I don't see other subsets for Raleway on Google Fonts.

Comment: where should i write these line? i can not modify auto fonts.googleapis.com's css..

Comment: I don't know Wordpress. https://www.google.com/fonts > Search for raleway > add to collection > hit use. There are the options on how to include it. You claim 'Raleway font has Turkish support.' but the one supplied at Google doesn't.

Comment: in 'Choose the character sets you want' section, there is only 'latin' option? no turkish.... ??

Comment: Yes, that is my updated answer: There is no Turkish subset in Raleway as supplied by Google Fonts. Google doesn't even have a Turkish subset category. I think (but am not sure) that Turkish will live in their latin extended set. Not that that is available for Raleway... Maybe via http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/raleway

Comment: @orhuncan let us know how you solved this. You might even write an answer to your own question and accept that. It's the answers that make SO a useful resource for all developers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Google Fonts doesn't offer Latin-extended subset of Raleway. Though, Raleway originally has it. You can you use it downloading from https://github.com/impallari/Raleway